# How to initialize Bluetooth in a startup script with Yocto Poky Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, yocto, intel-edison

I have a script that initializes my bluetooth setup on an Intel Edison.  It allows pairing and connecting to this headless machine running Yocto Poky Linux.  It was suggested that I put the startup script in /etc/init.d and run update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults.  The script ran but it didn't work (generated boot errors saying bluetooth device not found) because Bluetooth had not started yet.  I did some reasearch and after removing my links I did update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults 99 which was claimed to run the script last but it did't make any differrence -- it still ran in the same place in the boot sequence. I verified that the links had S99 on them so it seemed like they were set up correctly.  There is another post on SO asking a similar question but that was a Ubuntu system where mine is Poky Linux.  That solution suggested putting the startup script in a directory that does not exist on my system.  There were other suggestions, putting it in rc.local, which I did and got the same result, it runs before Bluetooth is initialized.

Here is my script. My program is called nmea_thread and is run last.  Everything else is initializing Bluetooth.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock bluetooth
/usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 up
/usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 piscan 
/usr/bin/hciconfig hic0 sspmode 0
/home/root/simpleAgent/simple-agent &
/home/root/nmea_thread
```

Answer (score 3):

Often bluetooth is initialized asynchronously, so you can't be sure that your script will be run after hci0 is added. Good solution is to wait for BT initialization in background:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "background" ]; then
     $0 background &
else
    #Wait until BT is initialized
    for ((i = 0; i <= 100; i++)) do
      hciconfig hci0 && break
      usleep 100000
    done
    /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock bluetooth
    /usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 up
    /usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 piscan 
    /usr/bin/hciconfig hic0 sspmode 0
    /home/root/simpleAgent/simple-agent &
    /home/root/nmea_thread 
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

hciattach is the correct way.
syntax

hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 3000000

Answer (score 1):

you need to flash the driver first before initializing it. Currently i don't remember how, but thats how i made it with raspberry pi and yocto.
Note if you use systemV, you can do call it from a script and it will work
Using SystemD, you need to make it in a service and wait. Falshing should be done in the two cases.